# select2 firing twice if initialized by class

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I've several dinamically generated select using a button, so i can identify it only by class.
The problem is that when `select2:selectevent` is fired, alert if fired N times, and not only where i changed the value.

How solve this? (I only can assign init plugin by class, no unique id)

```
<a id="add">Add new</a>

 <div id="container">
 </div>


$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#add").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

    $("#container").append('<select class="idFolder" name="idFolder[]"><option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="WY">Wyoming</option></select>');

    $('.idFolder').select2({
    width: '100%'
  }).on('select2:select', function(e) {
    var id = e.params.data.id;
    alert(id);
  });

  });

});
```

UPDATE with my real case: https://jsfiddle.net/1jaw6d1x/3/

Comment: are you saying that the event you are binding  `select2: select` is firing as many times as there are select2 in the page no matter if you change the option from only one of the selects? because from the given code it wont do any such thing you might have to add the actual view where you are doing this with the real code that is generating the selects

Comment: yes this appened

Comment: i couldnt get what you are saying

Comment: I've just modified your jsfiddle on my real case: https://jsfiddle.net/1jaw6d1x/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you have used involves iterating on all the select elements and then picking up the one you are trying to target you can avoid iterating on all of the selects using `.each()`. You can use a `counter` to avoid this situation and only bind the `select2` once on the newer element only.

That way you won't have to iterate all the selects and you would have already the index of the element to select from the collection, imagine adding 50 or more selects at 51st select it`.each()` would iterate all 50 first and then reach the 51st and then bind `select2`.

```
var objectS = $(".idFolder");

var currentSelect=    $(objectS[count]);
```

See demo below

```js
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#add").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#container").append('<select class="idFolder" name="idFolder[]"><option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="WY">Wyoming</option></select>');
    var objectS = $(".idFolder");
    var currentSelect = $(objectS[count])

    currentSelect.select2({
      width: '100%'
    }).on('select2:select', function(e) {
      var id = e.params.data.id;
      alert(id);
    });
    count++;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<a id="add">Add new</a>

<br><br>

<div id="container">


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've found another fix. see my answer

Comment: yeah, i just saw that you can avoid iterating on all of the selects using `.each()`, by using this answer as a solution, as the increase of select elements would make the script heavier to search all and then find only the targetted or newer select element. @GiuseppeLodiRizzini

Comment: just try hitting `Add New` continuously and see the result of both the scripts @GiuseppeLodiRizzini

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#add").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

    $("#container").append('<select class="idFolder" name="idFolder[]"><option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="WY">Wyoming</option></select>');

    $('.idFolder').each(function(){

      if ($(this).hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
          // Select2 has been initialized
      } else {

      $(this).select2({
      width: '100%'
      }).on('select2:select', function(e) {
      var id = e.params.data.id;
      alert(id);
      });

      }

    });

  });

});
```